# Bootstrap Column Push-Pull Trying Move Column Up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style a "team member" page: Picture to the right with name & role to the left of an image with a biography below. I've designed my layout for mobile, and I'm using push/pull but I'm getting a "float" (though I think it's functioning as intended.) [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgzSv.png).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
    <div class="row"><h1>John Roberts</h1></div>
    <div class="row"><h2>Chief Justice</h2></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 tmMbr_photoWithSocial">
    <img src="1200px-Official_roberts_CJ.jpg" class="tmMbr_photo img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Photo of Chief Justice John Roberts">
</div>

<div class="tmMbr_bio col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec egestas velit. Nulla convallis varius ex, eget iaculis elit mollis eu. In lobortis, nisi tincidunt blandit sagittis, diam nisl ornare felis, sit amet cursus ipsum risus vitae ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta ex rutrum, eleifend massa sit amet, tempus erat. Ut tincidunt lacus ac porttitor bibendum. Praesent consectetur lorem id euismod tincidunt. Maecenas ac fermentum mi, ut iaculis lorem. Nulla molestie hendrerit velit nec luctus. Cras fringilla sem sit amet lacus pellentesque, sodales venenatis augue blandit. Nunc a velit arcu.</p>
    <p>Vivamus nec ex est. Quisque vel luctus massa. Quisque vitae ullamcorper tellus. Nunc consectetur id dui eu congue. Aliquam rutrum nunc quis lacus efficitur imperdiet. Aliquam eget mauris non sem egestas pellentesque. Phasellus sed venenatis risus, eu vehicula nulla.</p>
</div>
```

This wraps correctly without the image, but once you load the any portrait image, the 'bio' block seems to want to clear itself. I've tried wrapping the elements in rows, etc, and searched like hell, but I can't figure this out.

Pretty much completely new to this, I'm writing hopefully for a (CSS?) solution but also to confirm that this behavior is as expected.

Comment: What you are seeing is correct behavior from Bootstrap. `.col` elements float left. When you use `push` and `pull` you are only adding left and right properties.  So what you have is the image div which is 4 columns and then the name div which is 8. That's 12. Bootstrap works on a 12 column grid, so when you add the bio div that's 8, it will "clear" both because the grid is out of space. Why don't you put the bio paragraphs in with the name and title? Unless you want the name above the photo on mobile. If that's the case, I recommend going the flexbox route.

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the `float` properties on the first col elements and drop the push/pull classes useless here :

```css
.tmMbr_bio.col-sm-8.fl-r,
.col-sm-8.fl-r
{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-8 fl-r">
    <div class="row"><h1>John Roberts</h1></div>
    <div class="row"><h2>Chief Justice</h2></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4  tmMbr_photoWithSocial">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x700&text=Official_roberts_CJ.jpg" class="tmMbr_photo img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Photo of Chief Justice John Roberts">
</div>

<div class="tmMbr_bio col-sm-8  fl-r">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec egestas velit. Nulla convallis varius ex, eget iaculis elit mollis eu. In lobortis, nisi tincidunt blandit sagittis, diam nisl ornare felis, sit amet cursus ipsum risus vitae ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta ex rutrum, eleifend massa sit amet, tempus erat. Ut tincidunt lacus ac porttitor bibendum. Praesent consectetur lorem id euismod tincidunt. Maecenas ac fermentum mi, ut iaculis lorem. Nulla molestie hendrerit velit nec luctus. Cras fringilla sem sit amet lacus pellentesque, sodales venenatis augue blandit. Nunc a velit arcu.</p>
    <p>Vivamus nec ex est. Quisque vel luctus massa. Quisque vitae ullamcorper tellus. Nunc consectetur id dui eu congue. Aliquam rutrum nunc quis lacus efficitur imperdiet. Aliquam eget mauris non sem egestas pellentesque. Phasellus sed venenatis risus, eu vehicula nulla.</p>
</div>
```